# I want to pass schema (metadata) as an argument from Spark dataframe/dataset (dataframe name as an argument)

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I want to pass schema (metadata) as an argument from Spark dataframe/dataset.

I m using spark 2.x

Code: (Sample)

//Define metadata like below.

```
val df_emp_metadata = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("emp_id", StringType,true),
    StructField("emp_hier_dt",DateType,true),
    StructField("dept_id",IntegerType,true)
  ))

  
val df_dept_metadata = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("dept_id", IntegerType,true),
    StructField("dept_name",StringType,true)
  ))
```

I want to pass the df_emp_metadata/df_dept_metadata as an argument while I am executing the Spark-Submit and pass it as a variable in schema below.

```
val meta_Data = arg(0)  //(df_emp_metadata or df_dept_metadata from Spark-Submit)

val readFileIn = spark.sqlContext.read
    .format("csv")
    .schema($meta_Data)
    .load("data/source_file.csv")
```

Spark is not allowing to pass the dataframe name as an argument.

Please suggest if any other alternative ways to do this in Spark/Scala programming.

Comment: if else with any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `if-else` statement. You can select it by putting `1` and `2` or else.

```
val argument = arg(0)

val schema = if (argument == "1") df_emp_metadata else df_dept_metadata 

val readFileIn = spark.sqlContext.read
    .format("csv")
    .schema(schema)
    .load("data/source_file.csv")
```